# Validate jsonpath expression not working for a single attribute

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

I have the following JSON document:

```
{
    "logVersion": 1,
    "id": "65eb093d-39ea-11e4-8481-0dcbed7e7494",
    "part": "e5818b35-39ea-11e4-9c1a-0ee3aaa24b07",
    "interaction": {
        "product": "IVR",
        "start": 1410463962299000,
        "finish": 0
    },
    "productData": {
        "timestamp": "2014-09-11T19:36:16.356Z",
        "name": "SessionEnded"
    }
}
```

I want to validate if the productData.name == 'SessionEnded'.  I tried the following:
`$.productData[?(@.name == 'SessionEnded')]` and `$.productData?(@.name == 'SessionEnded')`on this [jsonpath expression tester](http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think your jsonpath is ok.

```
 $.productData[?(@.name=='SessionEnded')]
```

works for me on this tester:   [1]: http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/